# Generate random integers between 0 and 9

Tags: python, random, integer

How can I generate random integers between 0 and 9 (inclusive) in Python?

For example, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`

Comment: this one is also userful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936993/how-can-i-create-a-random-number-that-is-cryptographically-secure-in-python `>>> from random import SystemRandom
>>> cryptogen = SystemRandom()
>>> [cryptogen.randrange(3) for i in range(20)]`

Comment: this works: `import random;
print(random.randint(0, 9))`

Answer (score 2597, accepted):

Try [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
from random import randrange
print(randrange(10))
```

Comment: In particular, secrets should be used in preference to the default pseudo-random number generator in the random module, which is designed for modelling and simulation, not security or cryptography.

Comment: To save anyone having to navigate to the secrets module to accomplish this:
`import secrets`
`secrets.randbelow(10)`

Comment: Note that the secrets module was first added to Python in version 3.6

Comment: @user3540325: Pre-3.6, a close approximation is creating an instance of `random.SystemRandom()` and calling the methods of that instance; `random.SystemRandom()`, like `secrets` (which I believe is implemented in terms of it) relies on OS-supplied cryptographic randomness (e.g. `CryptGenRandom` on Windows, `/dev/urandom` on UNIX-likes).

Answer (score 796):

Try [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint):

```
import random
print(random.randint(0, 9))
```

---

Docs state:

> ```
> random.randint(a, b)
> ```
>
> Return a random integer *N* such that `a <= N <= b`. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`.

Answer (score 188):

Try this:

```
from random import randrange, uniform

# randrange gives you an integral value
irand = randrange(0, 10)

# uniform gives you a floating-point value
frand = uniform(0, 10)
```

Answer (score 105):

```
from random import randint

x = [randint(0, 9) for p in range(0, 10)]
```

This generates 10 pseudorandom integers in range 0 to 9 inclusive.

Comment: I wanted only 10 rows (`RANDOM_LIMIT`) on trial run of 2,500 rows (`row_count`) so I used `random_row_nos = [randint(1, row_count) for p in range(0, RANDOM_LIMIT)]` based on this answer and it worked the first time!

Answer (score 94):

The [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module is new in Python 3.6. This is better than the [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#module-random) module for cryptography or security uses.

To randomly print an integer in the inclusive range 0-9:

```
from secrets import randbelow
print(randbelow(10))
```

For details, see [PEP 506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/).

Note that it really depends on the use case. With the `random` module you can set a random seed, useful for pseudorandom but reproducible results, and this is not possible with the `secrets` module.

`random` module is also faster (tested on Python 3.9):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("random.randrange(10)", setup="import random")
0.4920286529999771
>>> timeit.timeit("secrets.randbelow(10)", setup="import secrets")
2.0670733770000425
```

Comment: This would improve the answer and should be added. The more security minded answers should always be added if available.

Answer (score 75):

I would try one of the following:

**1.>  [numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html)**

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(15,))

print (X1)
>>> array([3, 0, 9, 0, 5, 7, 6, 9, 6, 7, 9, 6, 6, 9, 8])
```

**2.>  [numpy.random.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)**

```
import numpy as np
X2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(15,)).astype(int)

print (X2)
>>> array([8, 3, 6, 9, 1, 0, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0, 4])
```

**3.>  [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)**

```
import numpy as np
X3 = np.random.choice(a=10, size=15 )

print (X3)
>>> array([1, 4, 0, 2, 5, 2, 7, 5, 0, 0, 8, 4, 4, 0, 9])
```

**4.>  [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange)**

```
from random import randrange
X4 = [randrange(10) for i in range(15)]

print (X4)
>>> [2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5]
```

**5.>  [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)**

```
from random import randint
X5 = [randint(0, 9) for i in range(0, 15)]

print (X5)
>>> [6, 2, 6, 9, 5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 7, 4, 9, 6]
```

**Speed:**

► **np.random.uniform and **np.random.randint** are much faster** (~10 times faster) than **np.random.choice, random.randrange, random.randint** .

```
%timeit np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(15,))
>> 1.64 µs ± 7.83 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=(15,)).astype(int)
>> 2.15 µs ± 38.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit np.random.choice(a=10, size=15 )
>> 21 µs ± 629 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit [randrange(10) for i in range(15)]
>> 12.9 µs ± 60.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit [randint(0, 9) for i in range(0, 15)]
>> 20 µs ± 386 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Notes:**

> 1.> [np.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) generates random integers over the half-open interval [low, high).
>
> 2.> [np.random.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) generates uniformly distributed numbers over the half-open interval [low, high).
>
> 3.> [np.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) generates a random sample over the half-open interval [low, high) as if the argument `a` was np.arange(n).
>
> 4.> [random.randrange(stop)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) generates a random number from range(start, stop, step).
>
> 5.> [random.randint(a, b)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) returns a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.
>
> 6.> [astype(int)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) casts the numpy array to int data type.
>
> 7.> I have chosen size = (15,). This will give you a numpy array of length = 15.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: If that error occurs, have you installed numpy (`pip install numpy`) and have you imported it using `import numpy as np`?

Comment: random is a built-in module, why import it through numpy? Does numpy expand it?

Comment: @LightCC I suppose it's faster to generate *multiple* random numbers because it's in C and heavily optimized. Although getting a single number would probably be faster without all that overhead (try it and see, but don't go crazy with tiny optimizations)

Answer (score 36):

Choose the size of the array (in this example, I have chosen the size to be 20). And then, use the following:

```
import numpy as np   
np.random.randint(10, size=(1, 20))
```

You can expect to see an output of the following form (*different random integers will be returned each time you run it; hence you can expect the integers in the output array to differ from the example given below*).

```
array([[1, 6, 1, 2, 8, 6, 3, 3, 2, 5, 6, 5, 0, 9, 5, 6, 4, 5, 9, 3]])
```

Comment: It's also helpful to know how Numpy can generate a random array of specified size, not just a single random number. (Docs: [numpy.random.randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html))

Answer (score 32):

While many posts demonstrate how to get *one* random integer, the original question asks how to generate random integer**s** (plural):

> How can I generate random integers between 0 and 9 (inclusive) in Python?

For clarity, here we demonstrate how to get multiple random integers.

**Given**

```
>>> import random


lo = 0
hi = 10
size = 5
```

**Code**

*Multiple, Random Integers*

```
# A
>>> [lo + int(random.random() * (hi - lo)) for _ in range(size)]
[5, 6, 1, 3, 0]
```

```
# B
>>> [random.randint(lo, hi) for _ in range(size)]
[9, 7, 0, 7, 3]
```

```
# C
>>> [random.randrange(lo, hi) for _ in range(size)]
[8, 3, 6, 8, 7]
```

```
# D
>>> lst = list(range(lo, hi))
>>> random.shuffle(lst)
>>> [lst[i] for i in range(size)]
[6, 8, 2, 5, 1]
```

```
# E
>>> [random.choice(range(lo, hi)) for _ in range(size)]
[2, 1, 6, 9, 5]
```

*Sample of Random Integers*

```
# F
>>> random.choices(range(lo, hi), k=size)
[3, 2, 0, 8, 2]
```

```
# G
>>> random.sample(range(lo, hi), k=size)
[4, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

**Details**

Some posts demonstrate how to natively generate *multiple* random integers.<sup>1</sup>  Here are some options that address the implied question:

- *A*: [`random.random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) returns a random float in the range `[0.0, 1.0)`
- *B*: [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) returns a random integer `N` such that `a <= N <= b`
- *C*: [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) alias to `randint(a, b+1)`
- *D*: [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles a sequence in place
- *E*: [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) returns a random element from the non-empty sequence
- *F*: [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) returns `k` selections from a population (with replacement, Python 3.6+)
- *G*: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) returns `k` unique selections from a population (without replacement):<sup>2</sup>

See also R. Hettinger's [talk](https://youtu.be/UANN2Eu6ZnM?t=622) on Chunking and Aliasing using examples from the `random` module.

Here is a comparison of some random functions in the Standard Library and Numpy:

```
| | random                | numpy.random                     |
|-|-----------------------|----------------------------------|
|A| random()              | random()                         |
|B| randint(low, high)    | randint(low, high)               |
|C| randrange(low, high)  | randint(low, high)               |
|D| shuffle(seq)          | shuffle(seq)                     |
|E| choice(seq)           | choice(seq)                      |
|F| choices(seq, k)       | choice(seq, size)                |
|G| sample(seq, k)        | choice(seq, size, replace=False) |
```

You can also quickly convert one of many [distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/routines.random.html#distributions) in Numpy to a sample of random integers.<sup>3</sup>

*Examples*

```
>>> np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=10, size=size).astype(int)
array([17, 10,  3,  1, 16])

>>> np.random.poisson(lam=1, size=size).astype(int)
array([1, 3, 0, 2, 0])

>>> np.random.lognormal(mean=0.0, sigma=1.0, size=size).astype(int)
array([1, 3, 1, 5, 1])
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>Namely @John Lawrence Aspden, @S T Mohammed, @SiddTheKid, @user14372, @zangw, et al.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup>@prashanth mentions this module showing one integer.</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup>Demonstrated by @Siddharth Satpathy</sub>

Answer (score 30):

You need the `random` python module which is part of your standard library.
Use the code...

```
from random import randint

num1= randint(0,9)
```

This will set the variable `num1` to a random number between `0` and `9` inclusive.

Comment: You can also choose `randrange(10)`.

Answer (score 26):

Try this through `random.shuffle`

```
>>> import random
>>> nums = range(10)
>>> random.shuffle(nums)
>>> nums
[6, 3, 5, 4, 0, 1, 2, 9, 8, 7]
```

Comment: This is not a correct answer, and should be deleted.

Comment: @NicolasGervais This might not be the correct answer to the original question, but it is a useful answer nevertheless and so it deserve to stay right where it is.

Answer (score 18):

In case of continuous numbers [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint) or [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randrange) are probably the best choices but if you have several distinct values in a sequence (i.e. a `list`) you could also use [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> import random
>>> values = list(range(10))
>>> random.choice(values)
5
```

`choice` also works for one item from a not-continuous sample:

```
>>> values = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
>>> random.choice(values)
7
```

If you need it "cryptographically strong" there's also a [`secrets.choice`](https://docs.python.org/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice) in python 3.6 and newer:

```
>>> import secrets
>>> values = list(range(10))
>>> secrets.choice(values)
2
```

Comment: What if we want more numbers from the sequence?

Comment: If they should be without replacement: [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample). With replacement you could use a comprehension with `choice`: for example for a list containing 3 random values with replacement: `[choice(values) for _ in range(3)]`

Answer (score 14):

if you want to use numpy then use the following:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.random.randint(0,10))
```

Comment: You could tell something about "numpy".

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the link. But I intended to mean that you could have improved your answer by providing details before just quoting two lines of code; like for what reason would someone prefer to use it instead of something already built in.
Not that you're obliged to, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randrange(10)
3
>>> random.randrange(10)
1
```

To get a list of ten samples:

```
>>> [random.randrange(10) for x in range(10)]
[9, 0, 4, 0, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can try importing the random module from Python and then making it choose a choice between the nine numbers. It's really basic.

```
import random
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

You can try putting the value the computer chose in a variable if you're going to use it later, but if not, the print function should work as such:

```
choice = random.choice(numbers)
print(choice)
```

Answer (score 7):

Generating random integers between 0 and 9.

```
import numpy
X = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
print(X)
```

Output:

```
[4 8 0 4 9 6 9 9 0 7]
```

Answer (score 6):

Best way is to use import Random function

```
import random
print(random.sample(range(10), 10))
```

or without any library import:

```
n={} 
for i in range(10):
    n[i]=i

for p in range(10):
    print(n.popitem()[1])
```

here the [popitems](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.popitem) removes and returns an arbitrary value from the dictionary `n`.

Answer (score 5):

`random.sample` is another that can be used

```
import random
n = 1 # specify the no. of numbers
num = random.sample(range(10),  n)
num[0] # is the required number
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a mathematical approach but it works 100% of the time:

Let's say you want to use `random.random()` function to generate a number between `a` and `b`. To achieve this, just do the following:

`num = (b-a)*random.random() + a;`

Of course, you can generate more numbers.

Comment: This generates a `float` value. To get pure integers:  `num = int(round((b-a)*random.random(),1)) + a`

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation page for the [random](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html) module:

> Warning: The pseudo-random generators of this module should not be
> used for security purposes. Use os.urandom() or SystemRandom if you
> require a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator.

[random.SystemRandom](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html?highlight=random#random.SystemRandom), which was introduced in Python 2.4, is considered [cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).  It is still available in Python 3.7.1 which is current at time of writing.

```py
>>> import string
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
>>> import random
>>> random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
'8'
>>> random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
'1'
>>> random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
'8'
>>> random.SystemRandom().choice(string.digits)
'5'
```

Instead of `string.digits`, `range` could be used per some of the other answers along perhaps with a comprehension.  Mix and match according to your needs.

Comment: Nice verification process

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd add to these answers with `quantumrand`, which uses ANU's quantum number generator. Unfortunately this requires an internet connection, but if you're concerned with "how random" the numbers are then this could be useful.

https://pypi.org/project/quantumrand/

Example

```py
import quantumrand

number = quantumrand.randint(0, 9)

print(number)
```

Output: `4`

The docs have a lot of different examples including dice rolls and a list picker.

Comment: How could anyone expect to have an internet connection? :)  You could add code to catch connection exception and just return the standard `random.randrange(10)` in that case.

Comment: ANU website claim it's "true random". There's no such thing as "true random" in this universe, especially those numbers sent over the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with this for Python 3.6

```
str_Key = ""                                                                                                
str_RandomKey = ""                                                                                          
for int_I in range(128):                                                                                    
      str_Key = random.choice('0123456789')
      str_RandomKey = str_RandomKey + str_Key
```

Just add characters like 'ABCD' and 'abcd' or '^!~=-><' to alter the character pool to pull from, change the range to alter the number of characters generated.

Comment: Nitpick: str_RandomKey is not an integer as original poster required.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTURNS allows to not only simulate the random integers but also to define the associated distribution with the `UserDefined` defined class.

The following simulates 12 outcomes of the distribution.

```
import openturns as ot
points = [[i] for i in range(10)]
distribution = ot.UserDefined(points) # By default, with equal weights.
for i in range(12):
    x = distribution.getRealization()
    print(i,x)
```

This prints:

```
0 [8]
1 [7]
2 [4]
3 [7]
4 [3]
5 [3]
6 [2]
7 [9]
8 [0]
9 [5]
10 [9]
11 [6]
```

The brackets are there because`x` is a `Point` in 1-dimension.
It would be easier to generate the 12 outcomes in a single call to `getSample`:

```
sample = distribution.getSample(12)
```

would produce:

```
>>> print(sample)
     [ v0 ]
 0 : [ 3  ]
 1 : [ 9  ]
 2 : [ 6  ]
 3 : [ 3  ]
 4 : [ 2  ]
 5 : [ 6  ]
 6 : [ 9  ]
 7 : [ 5  ]
 8 : [ 9  ]
 9 : [ 5  ]
10 : [ 3  ]
11 : [ 2  ]
```

More details on this topic are here: http://openturns.github.io/openturns/master/user_manual/_generated/openturns.UserDefined.html

Answer (score 0):

> Generate random integers between 0 and 9

##### With `numpy`

If you're OK with having a numpy dependency, then since version 1.17, numpy has [Generators](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html), which are much faster than `randint`/`choice` etc. if you want to generate a lot of random integers (e.g. more than 10000 integers). To construct it, use `np.random.default_rng()`. Then to generate random integers, call `integers()` or `choice()`. It is much faster than the standard library if you want to generate a large list of random numbers (e.g. to generate 1 million random integers, numpy generators are about 3 times faster than numpy's `randint` and about 40 times faster than stdlib's `random`<sup>1</sup>).

For example, to generate 1 million integers between 0 and 9, either of the following could be used.

```py
import numpy as np
# option 1
numbers = np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 10, size=1000000)
# option 2
numbers = np.random.default_rng().choice(10, size=1000000)
```

By default, it uses PCG64 generator; however, if you want to use the Mersenne Twister generator which is used in `random` in the standard library, then you could pass its instance as a seeding sequence to `default_rng()` as follows.

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(np.random.MT19937())
numbers = rng.integers(0, 10, size=1000)
```

##### With `random`

If you're restricted to the standard library, and you want to generate a lot of random integers, then `random.choices()` is much faster than `random.randint()` or `random.randrange()`.<sup>2</sup> For example to generate 1 million random integers between 0 and 9:

```py
import random
numbers = random.choices(range(10), k=1000000)
```

---

**Some timing results**<sup>1</sup>

Tested on Python 3.12 and numpy 1.26.

```py
import timeit
import random
import numpy as np

def numpy_randint():
    return np.random.randint(0, 10, size=1000000)

def numpy_Gen_integers():
    return np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 10, size=1000000)

def numpy_Gen_choice():
    return np.random.default_rng().choice(10, size=1000000)

def random_randrange():
    return [random.randrange(10) for _ in range(1000000)]

def random_choices():
    return random.choices(range(10), k=1000000)


t1 = min(timeit.repeat(numpy_randint, number=100))      # 1.9559144999366254
t2 = min(timeit.repeat(numpy_Gen_integers, number=100)) # 0.6704635999631137
t3 = min(timeit.repeat(numpy_Gen_choice, number=100))   # 0.6696784000378102
t4 = min(timeit.repeat(random_randrange, number=100))   # 64.98768060002476
t5 = min(timeit.repeat(random_choices, number=100))     # 25.686857299879193
```

<sub><sup>2</sup> If we look at their source implementations, `random.randrange()` (and `random.randint()` because it is the former's syntactic sugar) use a [while-loop to generate a pseudo-random number](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6592976061a6580fee2ade3564f6497eb685ab67/Lib/random.py#L248-L249) via [`_randbelow` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6592976061a6580fee2ade3564f6497eb685ab67/Lib/random.py#L308) while `random.choices()` calls `random()` once and uses it to [index the population](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6592976061a6580fee2ade3564f6497eb685ab67/Lib/random.py#L467). So if a lot of pseudo-random numbers need to be generated, the cost of this while-loop adds up.</sub>