# Python Random number generator and currency system for text-based RPG

Tags: python, random, python-2.7

Before I start, I will say that I am a new to programming. I just started with python, and am making a hobby project--an text-based role playing game. At one point, I want random numbers, lets say just for example: from 1-10 to be randomly generated. Also, I am interested in making a money system. Lets say I buy food, and for that I got +20 health and from my
character -10 money. How would I do that?

Comment: Not my -1, but to avoid them in future, start by asking one question at a time, and tell us what you've tried for yourself already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: generate random integers between 0 and 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/python-generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a random number, you could do...

```
import random
print random.randint(1,10)
```

For your money system, you could use a dictionary.

```
d={'money':100, 'health':100}
def buyBread():
  d[money]=d[money]-10
  d[health]=d[health]+20
```

The [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org) and Google are good places to read about Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) module in the standard library.

Comment: I already import random command but don t know how to use it. Okay i tray that module thanks... anybody about this currency

Comment: def Pizzeria():
    global money
    global health
    pizza = raw_input ("Good day you come to Pizzeria... You entered in and cashier say to you, good day sir what would you lik to buy. Do you whant, Eat something(HERE SHOULD BE MONEY SYSTEM LIK I BUY PIZZA AND GET -10 OF MY money AND +20 health...)? (1), Get a job(HERE I WANT RANDOM to get random amount of money)? (2)"
    if pizza == "1":

Comment: From the sounds of it, I think you should be starting with Hello World and working up to Pizzeria(), maybe in a couple months at least.