# Correct way to generate random numbers in Cython?

Tags: python, random, numpy, cython

What is the most efficient and portable way to generate a random random in `[0,1]` in Cython? One approach is to use `INT_MAX` and `rand()` from the C library:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand
cdef extern from "limits.h":
    int INT_MAX
cdef float randnum = rand() / float(INT_MAX)
```

Is it OK to use `INT_MAX` in this way? I noticed that it's quite different from the constant you get from Python's max int:

```
import sys
print INT_MAX
print sys.maxint
```

yields:

```
2147483647  (C max int)
9223372036854775807  (python max int)
```

Which is the right "normalization" number for `rand()`?  **EDIT** additionally, how can the random seed be set (e.g. seeded based on current time) if one uses the C approach of calling `rand()` from libc?

Comment: Have you just tried taking the max and min of a few thousand samples, and seeing which scaling factor gets near `1.0`?

Comment: Please watch "[rand() considered harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C standard says `rand` returns an `int` in the range 0 to RAND_MAX inclusive, so dividing it by RAND_MAX (from `stdlib.h`) is the proper way to normalise it. In practice, RAND_MAX will almost always be equal to MAX_INT, but don't rely on that.

Because `rand` has been part of ISO C since C89, it's guaranteed to be available everywhere, but no guarantees are made regarding the quality of its random numbers. If portability is your main concern, though, it's your best option, unless you're willing to use Python's `random` module.

Python's [`sys.maxint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.maxint) is a different concept entirely; it's just the largest positive number Python can represent in *its own* int type; larger ones will have to be longs. Python's ints and longs aren't particularly related to C's.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how the seed can be set using the libc approach?

Comment: I'd probably use `random.randint(0, INT_MAX)` for that, really. Overhead isn't an issue because it will only happen once.

Comment: overhead is a major issue since this is called many times in a loop that needs to generate random numbers (in order to sample from multinomial in part). Can I set `random.randint(0, INT_MAX)` and then call C's `rand()` and have the C and Python seeds be "in sync"?

Comment: to clarify: overhead is only an issue for the generation of numbers, of course as you say calling python back once to set the seed is not an issue at all

Comment: I meant use `random.randint(0, INT_MAX)` as an argument to libc's `srand`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if drand is a new addition but it seems to do exactly what you want while avoiding the costly division.

```
cdef extern from "stdlib.h":
    double drand48()
    void srand48(long int seedval)

cdef extern from "time.h":
    long int time(int)

# srand48(time(0))
srand48(100)
# TODO: this is a seed to reproduce bugs, put to line of code above for
# production
drand48() #This gives a float in range [0,1)
```

I came across [this idea](https://xor0110.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/how-to-generate-floating-point-random-numbers-efficiently/) while researching if your division method generated sufficient randomness. The source I found makes the good point that in my case I am comparing the random number to a decimal with two digits so I really only need 3 decimal points of precision. So INT_MAX is more than adequate. But, it seems like drand48 saves the cost of division so might be worth using.

Comment: By the way, this is not portable because `srand48` and `drand48` are only available on POSIX systems

Answer (score 3):

'c' stdlib rand() returns a number between 0 and RAND_MAX which is generally 32767.

Is there any reason not to use the python random() ?

[Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/python-generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Comment: I am using this an inner loop in a Cython function and calling Python for this is too costly

Comment: RAND_MAX is 2147483647 (2**31-1) on my system. It's guaranteed to be *at least* 2**15-1, but I don't think I've ever seen it that low in practice.

Comment: Oh, apparently msvc's is 2**15-1. That's awful.

Comment: Yes. There is a reason which is time reduction. Using the native C rand() function reduced the time by 300 ms less than using numpy.rand().

Answer (score 3):

All of the above answers are correct, but I'd like to add a note that took me way too long to catch. The C rand() function is NOT thread-safe. So if you are running cython in parallel without the gil, the standard C rand() function has a chance of causing enormous slowdowns while it tries to handle all of the kernel calls. Just a warning.

Comment: That's a good point. I think it could generate the same "random" numbers in each thread or just corrupt its internal state or something else. The slowdown you see is one way that "not thread-safe" could show up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976880/canonical-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-cython?noredirect=1&lq=1 covers this I think

Answer (score 0):

As shown below, I see no reason to not prefer python `random.random()`:

```py
import numpy as np
from ext.random import random as rd
%timeit rd()
48.6 ns ± 0.396 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

np.unique([rd() for _ in range(10000000)]).size
Out[5]: 32768

from random import random as rd_python
%timeit rd_python()
33.2 ns ± 0.213 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)

np.unique([rd_python() for _ in range(10000000)]).size
Out[8]: 10000000
```

for cython version:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX

cpdef float random():
    return float(rand()) / RAND_MAX
```

same values for the version:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX

cdef float scale = 1.0 / RAND_MAX
cpdef float crandom():
    return rand() * scale
```

Comment: This isn't a great test though. It's showing that they take about the same length of time to call from Python. However if you call them from Cython itself then you can get significant speed-up calling a C function but not when calling `np.random`

Comment: @DavidW as I found, for bigger random numbers count calling big np.random once can be faster than calling cython random many times; so it is not so obviously