# Canonical way to generate random numbers in Cython

Tags: multithreading, random, cython

What is the best way to generate pseudo uniform random numbers (a double in [0, 1)) that is:

1. Cross platform (ideally with same same sample sequence)
2. Thread safe (explicit passing of the mutated state of the prng or 
   using a thread-local state internally)
3. Without GIL lock
4. Easily wrappable in Cython

There was a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138090/correct-way-to-generate-random-numbers-in-cython) over 3 years ago about this but a lot of the answers don't meet all criteria. For example, `drand48` is POSIX-specific.

The only method I'm aware of, which seems (but not sure) to meet <s>all</s> some criteria is:

```
from libc.stdlib cimport rand, RAND_MAX

random = rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
```

Note @ogrisel [asked](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/9UGMi_b3tVo) the same question about 3 years ago.

**Edit**

Calling [rand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161322/using-stdlibs-rand-from-multiple-threads) is not thread safe. Thanks for pointing that out @DavidW.

Comment: I don't think `rand` is threadsafe. I'd look at wrapping the C++ standard library random functions (but I don't have an example of it myself)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Big pre-answer caveat: this answer recommends using C++ because the question specifically asks for a solution that runs without the GIL**. If you don't have this requirement (and you probably don't...) then Numpy is the simplest and easiest solution. Provided that you're generating large amounts of numbers at a time you will find Numpy perfectly quick. Don't be misled into a complicated exercise in wrapping C++ because someone asked for a no-gil solution.

---

**Original answer:**

I think the easiest way to do this is to use the C++11 standard library which provides [nice encapsulated random number generators and ways to use them](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/). This is of course not the only options, and you could wrap pretty much any suitable C/C++ library (one good option might be to use whatever library numpy uses, since that's most likely already installed).

My general advice is to only wrap the bits you need and not bother with the full hierarchy and all the optional template parameters. By way of example I've shown one of the default generators, fed into a uniform float distribution.

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: extra_compile_args = -std=c++11

cdef extern from "<random>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass mt19937:
        mt19937() # we need to define this constructor to stack allocate classes in Cython
        mt19937(unsigned int seed) # not worrying about matching the exact int type for seed
    
    cdef cppclass uniform_real_distribution[T]:
        uniform_real_distribution()
        uniform_real_distribution(T a, T b)
        T operator()(mt19937 gen) # ignore the possibility of using other classes for "gen"
        
def test():
    cdef:
        mt19937 gen = mt19937(5)
        uniform_real_distribution[double] dist = uniform_real_distribution[double](0.0,1.0)
    return dist(gen)
```

(The `-std=c++11` at the start is for GCC. For other compilers you may need to tweak this. Increasingly c++11 is a default anyway, so you can drop it)

With reference to your criteria:

1. Cross platform on anything that supports C++. I believe the sequence should be specified so it's repeatable.
2. Thread safe, since the state is stored entirely within the `mt19937` object (each thread should have its own `mt19937`).
3. No GIL - it's C++, with no Python parts
4. Reasonably easy.

---

**Edit:** about using `discrete_distribution`.

This is a bit harder because the constructors for `discrete_distribution` are less obvious how to wrap (they involve iterators). I think the easiest thing to do is to go via a C++ vector since support for that is built into Cython and it is readily convertable to/from a Python list

```
# use Cython's built in wrapping of std::vector
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "<random>" namespace "std":
    # mt19937 as before
    
    cdef cppclass discrete_distribution[T]:
        discrete_distribution()
        # The following constructor is really a more generic template class
        # but tell Cython it only accepts vector iterators
        discrete_distribution(vector.iterator first, vector.iterator last)
        T operator()(mt19937 gen)

# an example function
def test2():
    cdef:
        mt19937 gen = mt19937(5)
        vector[double] values = [1,3,3,1] # autoconvert vector from Python list
        discrete_distribution[int] dd = discrete_distribution[int](values.begin(),values.end())
    return dd(gen)
```

Obviously that's a bit more involved than the uniform distribution, but it's not impossibly complicated (and the nasty bits could be hidden inside a Cython function).

Comment: Thanks. As an aside, how can one use the discrete distribution found in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/? Still not familiar merging C++ and Cython.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for your help.