# Python: Assigning Random Integer to Variables in a Class

Tags: python, random, integer

I have a large amount of variables within a class like this:

```
class Variables:
  num1 = "Text 1"

  num2 = "Text 2"

  num3 = "Text 3"
```

and so and  so forth. I need to assign each variable a specific number from range (1,30) so that within the class, each variable is represented by a different integer value. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9

Comment: Python does not use a `var` declaration!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Later in the program, I want to be able to get user input in order to call a variable. Its mainly for a game I'm building based on random functions and user input.

Comment: As you defined these variables are `static class members` do you realy want this kind of vars?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to python, and have some minor experience in JS. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: @Arthur: I think you would be better off using a dict or list instead of lots of variables!

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell Okay, thanks. I'll look into using dict given that I have a long series

Comment: I was thinking the same thing! See my answer. If you can give any more context on exactly why you're doing this, it will make it easier to show you something more useful!

Comment: As Hugh Bothwell said, mapping values to names like this is _exactly_ the kind of thing a `dict` is for.  As a bonus, a `dict` can use integers as its keys, so you wouldn't have to glue strings and stringified integers together into names like `var27`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of data in your class that looks like 'name' (at the moment you're using a variable num1, num2 etc for the name) and each 'name' maps to a 'value' (at the moment your values look like "Text 1", "Text 2" etc.

You might find it easier to use a dictionary for this data, rather than trying to define each name:value as a separate variable = value.

For example, you'd end up with something more like:

```
class Variables(object):
    numbers = {
        "num1": "Text 1",
        "num2": "Text 2",
        "num3": "Text 3",
    }
```

Now it becomes much more straightforward to procedurally generate (a fancy way of saying automatically) that dictionary:

```
class Variables(object):
    numbers = {
        "num{}".format(i): "Text {}".format(i)
        for i in range(100)
    }
```

Now if you want them to be random numbers:

```
import random

class Variables(object):
    numbers = {
        "num{}".format(i): "Text {}".format(random.randrange(100))
        for i in range(100)
    }

v = Variables()
print v.numbers["num50"]
```

Comment: thanks so much for the feedback. I ran the code in the Python IDLE and adjusted it a little bit to fit my parameters and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
class Variables():
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(1, 31):
            setattr(self, 'num{}'.format(i), 'Text {}'.format(i))

v = Variables()

print v.num1 # Text 1
print v.num30 # Text 30
```

Comment: He mean random integer I think

Comment: Ya, random integer. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Arman - OP said *assign each variable a specific number from range (1,30)*. Shouldn't take much to convert this to random numbers, but you wouldn't know which fields are defined on the class.

Comment: @cricket_007 In question title he said Assign Random Integer between this range

Answer (score 0):

First you create your variables and add them to a dictionary :

```
dic = {num1:"Text 1", num2 : "text2",..}
```

next create a Variables obejct:

```
  a = Variables()
```

then call set_dic class method:

```
  a.set_dic(dic)
```

its assgin each variable a random integer between 1,30

```
from random import randint  
class Variables:
      def __init__(self):
            self.dic = {}
      def set_dic(self, dic):
            self.dic =  dic
            for x in dic:
                  dic[x] = randint(1,30)
```