# How do I set a random speed for my Turtle each time I run the code?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to make a Turtle racing game (using Python - Turtle) but I can't figure out how to set a random speed for each turtle everytime I run the code (so that Turtle x won't win every time)

```
#define race fuction. Move each Turtle fd(random number between 2-10)  
red.pensize(10)
blue.pensize(10)
green.pensize(10)
red.speed(random)
blue.speed(random)
green.speed(random)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Answer (score 0):

Setting `turtle.speed()` to any value, including the result of `random.randint()`, is neither necessary nor sufficient.  It's simply convenient.  Below is my minimalist turtle racing code.  The `turtle.speed()` method is used as a place to stash the turtle's speed but if you change:

```
turtle.forward(turtle.speed() + 1)
```

to a fixed value:

```
turtle.forward(10)
```

you'll see that the turtles all move at the same rate, regardless of the setting of `turtle.speed()`.  The `turtle.speed()` value only determines how quickly a turtle draws its update.  Ultimately differences in the argument to `turtle.forward()` control the amount of forward motion:

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

TURTLE_SIZE = 20
MAXIMUM_SPEED = 10
DEFAULTS = {'shape':"turtle", 'visible': False}

screen = Screen()

starting_line = TURTLE_SIZE - screen.window_width()/2
finish_line = screen.window_width()/2 - TURTLE_SIZE - MAXIMUM_SPEED

turtles = dict(red=Turtle(**DEFAULTS), green=Turtle(**DEFAULTS), blue=Turtle(**DEFAULTS))

for i, (color, turtle) in enumerate(turtles.items()):
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(starting_line, i * TURTLE_SIZE)
    turtle.speed(randint(0, MAXIMUM_SPEED))
    turtle.showturtle()

racing = True

while racing:
    for turtle in turtles.values():
        turtle.forward(turtle.speed() + 1)
        if turtle.xcor() >= finish_line:
            racing = False
            break

screen.exitonclick()
```

To get turtle racing that's any more sophisticated, you probably need to work with the `ontimer()` event to allow them to move more independently.

[image]