# Delete specific row and corresponding file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I want to delete 90% of rows which have "steering" value qual to 0. And there is a corresponding image file for all three f them, center, left and right. I want to delete them too. The csv file is like this:[image]

I have written the following code to at least get the files which have steering value 0. All I need is the code to randomly get 90% of those files and delete them.

```
with open('data/driving_log.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for i,line in enumerate(reader):
        lines.append(line)
        index.append(i)

lines = np.delete(lines,(0), axis = 0)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    #print(type(line[3].astype(np.float)))
    line_no.append(line[3].astype(np.float32))
    #print(line_no[i])
    if line_no[i]==0.0:
          # this gets the first column of the row.
        for j in range(3):
            source_path = line[j]
            filename = source_path.split('/')[-1]
            print(filename)
        count += 1
```

Comment: Have you searched for how to generate random numbers & delete files in python?

[Generate random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9).

[Deleting files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996603/how-to-delete-a-file-or-folder).

Comment: Yes, I need to import random and use os.remove() to remove the file. But, I'm getting confused in two places, removing a row form the csv file and randomly removing 90% of the files which have steering value equal to 0.

Comment: Could you post a portion of your CSV file in text format? Preferably with commas as the delimiter.

Comment: Also, your code is incomplete. Lots of undefined variables.

Comment: IMG/center_2016_12_01_13_30_48_287.jpg, IMG/left_2016_12_01_13_30_48_287.jpg, IMG/right_2016_12_01_13_30_48_287.jpg, 0, 0, 0, 22.14829.

Comment: I have added the portion of the code from where it starts working. Before that it's just importing packages and initializing variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
import csv
from random import randint
from os import remove

# Create a 2D list from which we can work with
lines = []
with open('data/driving_log.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for line in reader:
        lines.append(line)

# Find 10% of total lines (to keep), not including header row
numToKeep = round(sum(1 for i in lines if i[3] == '0') * 0.1)

# Save 10% of lines to a new 2D list
toKeep = []
for i in range(numToKeep):
    while True:
        index = randint(1, len(lines)-1)
        # Make sure we haven't already selected the same line
        if lines[index] not in toKeep and lines[index][3] == '0':
            toKeep.append(lines[index])
            break

# Deleting all files of the selected 90% of rows
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i == 0:  # Omit the header row
        continue
    if lines[i][3] != '0':  # Keep rows that don't have a steering value of 0
        toKeep.append(lines[i])
    if line not in toKeep:
        print("Deleting: {}".format(line))
        for i in range(3):
            remove(line[i])

with open('data/driving_log.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows([lines[0]])  # Put the header back in
    writer.writerows(toKeep)
```

I realize this isn't the most elegant solution. I'm not familiar with numpy and don't have time to learn it right now, but this should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. But I don't see the condition where the steering angle needs to be 0. Plus, I also want to delete the corresponding files. like I want to delete `center_2016_12_01_13_30_48_287.jpg` in the IMG folder. Can you help me with these two things?

Comment: This line `if lines[index] not in toKeep and lines[index][3] == '0':` states that if we haven't already added the line to our list of lines to keep AND if the steering column is equal to 0, then...

Comment: These lines: `for i in range(3):` AND `remove(line[i])` will delete each of the 3 files for that particular row.