# How to set a percentage chance to make something

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I making a fighting game. Its like there are two players. They have 100 hp and they choose attack value btween 0-100 when they're fighting. After they choose value they should have %(100-value) chance of being successful with this attack. For example if they choose value 60, they have %40 chance to be successful with this attack.Can you please help. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So if they choose `0`...

Comment: I think you don't want to have them choose, no? Maybe you want to choose for them? So `import random; print random.random() * 100`. Even better `import random; print random.randint(1, 100)`

Comment: So your question is, "how does the `random` module work"? That's too much to answer in one question.

Comment: I'd suggest you try your best to do what you need and come back when you have some specific question. You can take the [random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module and run it through a translator, which will help you understand the module in a general sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Comment: @smac89 I see no problem in an attack doing no damage succeeding 100% of the time.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien exactly my point. What would be the point of having them choose if they would always choose 0 anyways?

Comment: @smac89 If you pick a low value, you have a weak attack with a high chance of succeeding. If you pick a high value, you have a strong attack with a low chance of succeeding. Both extremes—an attack that always succeeds but does no damage, or an attack that does maximum damage but never succeeds—are useless, so I don't see why anyone would pick either. Still, choosing between high damage + high risk or low damage + low risk does make sense, based on how lucky you're feeling. :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is to generate a random number between `0` and `100` and check if it's greater than your inserted number.

For example, if you enter 50, there's a 50% chance the random number will be greater (or equal), 50% lower. If you enter 10, there's a 90% chance the number will be greater.

You can use [`random.randrange(101)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) to generate a random number between 0 and 100 inclusive. Then it's a simple comparison to your value, and that should be all you need.

Comment: 0-100 is a range of 101

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in statistics, a chance is expressed as a number between 0 and 1, so 0.6 represents a 60% chance. Then, if you want to have a 0.6 chance of success, you can determine success or not by picking a random floating point number between 0 and 1 and check if it is smaller than or equal to 0.6.

Intuitively, you can look at it this way:

```
|-----------------------------------|-----------------------|
0                                  0.6                      1
```

If you'd pick a random point on this line—your random number between 0 and 1—the chance of it being on the left side of the 0.6 is... 0.6 (60%).

You can use [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.uniform) for this:

```
import random
success_rate_percentage = 60
success = random.uniform(0, 1) <= success_rate_percentage / 100.0
```

Now as a simple check if this is functioning properly:

```
>>> import random
>>> success_count = 0
>>> for _ in range(100000):
...     if random.uniform(0, 1) <= 0.6
...         success_count += 1
...
>>> success_count
59954
```

The expected result is about 0.6 * 100000 = 60000 successes and the actual result is 59954, so that's close enough.

Comment: This is a really good and underrated answer!