# Import `random` affecting for loop

Tags: python, random, import

I want to print the numbers 1 to 10 with a `for` loop, but `import random` is affecting my `for` loop and the loop is running twice. Here is a [screenshot of my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Krum.png). The output is displayed below. Can you explain to me why this happens?

```
import random
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)
```

My output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem - did exactly the same thing as OP, got normal result.

Comment: Pretty sure you called your own script `random.py`. Now it's importing itself.

Comment: I am also not able to reproduce this. Are you sure you didn't just accidentally run your program twice?

Comment: You don't need to import random. As h4z3 mentioned, I couldn't reproduce the problem. If you want to print 10, your range should be (1,11).

Comment: I agree with Matthias

Comment: As @Matthias pointed out, you called your script `random.py`. Please rename your file to some other name and run.

Comment: *Facepalm* I cant believe that its true its name is random.py. Sorry for taking your time

Comment: I think is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will never happen.

make sure you are running the latest version of your program, and make sure you didn't paste the same code at some other place in the same file. e.g. make sure you don't have a precompiled version of it. (e.g. change the file name and try again).

Update:

based on the comment by matthias, if you saved your file as random.py the above result could be reproduced.

```
# if you save the code below as random.py
import random
for i in range(1,10):
    print(i)



# your output could be reproduced as below.
>>> python random.py

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
```

solution: change the file name or if you have to import it make sure you include the codition `if __name__ == "__main__"` in before the for loop of your random.py

Answer (score -2):

11I do not see any problem, I did the example and it works perfect.

My output: 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Could it be that you have called the file twice? It's the only request I find.