# Random values of a list

Tags: python

I have made this code below :

```
a = list(input("Enter some numbers"))
b = list(input("Enter some numbers"))

c = a + b

def PuzzleKey():
    """
    the variable c sums a and b, and if their sum is equal to 2O20, we multiply them
    """
    if c == 2020: 
        return a * b

print(PuzzleKey())
```

Instead of lines 1-2, I need to generate random values instead of creating ones myself, how can I do that?

Comment: How can adding two *lists* produce an integer (._.)? Do you mean `c = sum(a + b)`?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9/3996930#3996930?

Comment: Is your input requiring more than one `int` for `a` and `b`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - The post you've linked is asking about a single random value. And this one is asking for multiple inputs for each variable (a, b) since the wording is "Enter some numbers" and it's stored in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `randrange` function will return you a random integer between zero and your argument:

```
from random import randrange

a = randrange(1000)
b = randrange(1000)
```

Also, you can pass specific arguments to this function:

```
randrange(start, stop[, step])
```

Comment: I feel seriously dumb after finding that answer, my question isn't worth to ask in stack overflow, I think

Comment: does it send the output already or I have to run this program several times until it sends an output?

Comment: This solution binds the value of `randrange()` once it it is called. Also, the question ask for a list of integers it appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
x=random.randint(lowerNumber,higherNumber)
```

Comment: This solution binds the value of randint once it is called. Also, the question ask for a list of integers. If this is put into a list multiple times, it will be the same value.

Answer (score 0):

The random value should be defined in a separate function. This way it will be able to be called on easily throughout the program.

```
import random

def rand_int(lower, upper):
     return random.randint(lower, upper)
```

Output -

```
>>> rand_int(1,10)
4
>>> rand_int(1,10)
3
```

Incorporating it with your script, for example -

```
>>> a = [rand_int(1,10), rand_int(1,11), rand_int(1,17)]
>>> a
[6, 10, 14]
```