# Trying to create a list of 10 random numbers between 1-10 that do not repeat in python

Tags: python, random

This is not the whole program I want to write but right now I'm just trying to figure out this simple thing.  And if you couldn't tell, I am completely new to programming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How do I create a list of random numbers without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755538/364696). Would have dupehammered if I hadn't voted to close for lack of focus, oops.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
random.sample(range(10), 10)
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(1, 11), 10)` if they must start at 1 and end at 10.

Comment: and what to write to print

Comment: @algsim: You need to actually run through a tutorial; printing a `list` item by item is so basic it's not worth covering here. Learn the basics of the language *then* ask questions about more complicated topics, don't learn it by asking a question for literally everything and having an understanding of it with glaring gaps.

Comment: `sample` is the best one-liner, but it is slightly less performant when you need to get all the values anyway; if you need to do this a lot (and are okay with two statements instead of one expression), the faster solution for "randomize order of all values" is `lst = [*range(10)]` (or `lst = list(range(10))` if you don't like unpacking generalizations), followed by `random.shuffle(lst)`.