# Loop through a tuple and printing each loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, tuples

I'm randomly generating a tuple from a dictionary. I want to run this a random number of times, and each run should return a true or false. How do I run this randomly N times and also have a counter and print out the amount of times it's True?

Comment: Can you share your code for tuple generation? You want to return True or False based on what criteria?

Comment: Are you having trouble generating a random number? Or using that randomly-generated number in a for loop?

Comment: Related, probably one of a couple of good duplicate targets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to generate a random number within a specified number range:

`n = random.randint(0, 10)`

Then, you need to add a base counter from which to count onto for each of the specified `True` outcomes:

```
reds = 0
blacks = 0
```

When iterating with a `for` loop, you need to set the starting point and ending point. You were missing the starting index and a colon here. You say you want to loop a random number of times, which is where `n` comes into play:

```
for i in range(0, n):
```

If the conditions are met, you want to increment either the `reds` or `blacks` variable by one, so you're able to see how many of each condition were `True`. I'd recommend changing your operator from `<` or `>` to `<=` or `>=`. As it's written, you aren't handling the third iteration of the loop. I left it in in my example below, because I'm not sure what your desired outcome is there.

At the end, you have something like this:

```
    n = random.randint(0, 10)
    bag = {}
    reds = 0
    blacks = 0
    for i in range(0, n):
        if i < 3:
            bag[i] = 'red'
            reds+=1
        elif i > 3 and i < 10:
            bag[i] = 'black'
            blacks+=1

        entry_list = list(bag.items())
        random_entry = random.choice(entry_list)
        print(random_entry)
    print(reds)
    print(blacks)
```

```
(0, 'red')
(1, 'red')
(2, 'red')
(1, 'red')
(1, 'red')
(5, 'black')
(6, 'black')
(4, 'black')
(8, 'black')
3
5
```

If you wanted to also explicitly keep track of `True` and `False` runs for each variable, you just add a little logic for that, as such:

```
    blackfalse = True
    redfalse = True
    for i in range(0, n):
        if i < 3:
            bag[i] = 'red'
            reds+=1
            blackfalse = True
            redfalse = False
        elif i > 3 and i < 10:
            bag[i] = 'black'
            blacks+=1
            redfalse = True
            blackfalse = False
        print(redfalse)
        print(blackfalse)
```