# How can we select a random hex value from a given hex range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, hex

If I have a hex range as `0x2080000000-0x217fffffff`, and if I need to select a random hex number or multiple hex number from this range, How can I do that using python?

Comment: Use `randint` from the `random` module. What do you need the numbers for? Do  you need cryptographically-secure sources of randomness?

Comment: Yeah but from I don't need a decimal number, I need a hex number right. From randint, does it return a hex number also? I need it for some system level code.

Comment: The hex values you provided **are** integers.

Comment: There's no such thing as a hexadecimal number *per se*. There is however the hexadecimal "representation" of a number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) from the `random` module:

```
from random import randint 

x = randint(0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff)
print(f"Decimal    : {x}\n"
      f"Hexadecimal: {hex(x)}")
```

The above draws a random integer in the closed interval `[0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff]` and assigns it to `x`. It then uses the built-in function [hex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex) to get the hexadecimal representation (as a string) of integer `x`.

**Sample Output**

```
Decimal    : 140929308832
Hexadecimal: 0x20d00a98a0
```

**Multiple random integers**

---

If you need multiple random integers in the closed interval `[0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff]` *without repetition*, you can use [sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

```
from random import sample

y = sample(range(0x2080000000, 0x2180000000), 10)
```

This returns a 10-element `list` of random integers in the aforementioned closed interval without duplicates. Notice the use of `0x2180000000` instead of `0x217fffffff` as [range(start, stop)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) yields integers in the half-open interval `[start, stop)` so we need to add `0x217fffffff` by 1 so that `range(0x2080000000, 0x2180000000)` yields integers in the closed interval `[0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff]`.

If you do not care about repetition, you can use

```
y = [randint(0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff) for i in range(10)]
```

to create a 10-element `list` of random integers in the closed interval (duplication is possible).

**Cryptographically-secure random numbers**

---

If you need cryptographically-secure randomness, first execute ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom))

```
from random import SystemRandom

rgen = SystemRandom()
```

Then, instead of

- using `randint()`, use `rgen.randint()`;
- using `sample()`, use `rgen.sample()`.

Answer (score 1):

Python stores the hex as an int so you can use random.randint() which receives two integers to define a range and returns an integer within the range, then you can cast the resulting integer to a hex.

```
from random import randint

my_hex = hex(randint(0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff))
print(my_hex)
```

which prints a random hex:

```
0x20c30ad886
```

To pick several hex numbers use random.choices, then cast the resulting integer  list into a hex list

```
from random import choices

hex_list = [hex(i) for i in choices(range(0x2080000000, 0x217fffffff), k=5)]
print(hex_list)
```

list of hex numbers

```
['0x2146f52eae', '0x212b07a57c', '0x20afd61152', '0x20e5ad73b9', '0x21620afcb3']
```

Comment: Thanks! I think both the solutions working for me