# How to choose random values in an range?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(0,500,10):
        xsnake=random(i)
for b in range(0,500,10):
        ysnake=random(b)
```

Hello, I wanted to know how I can choose randomly in the i of range in the variable below.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [random.randrange](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

```py
    import random
    print(random.randrange(0,500,10)
```