# How to get a random value from a dictionary that is in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, random

So I have a list (shown below) and I need to randomly access one of the dictionaries in a list, and print it out:

e.g. Instagram, 346, Social media platform, United States

I've tried to google and search for it, but whatever I tried it didn't work. I know how to print out the whole list, but I don't know how to print a single dictionary randomly.

```
    data = [
{
    'name': 'Instagram',
    'follower_count': 346,
    'description': 'Social media platform',
    'country': 'United States'
},
{
    'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo',
    'follower_count': 215,
    'description': 'Footballer',
    'country': 'Portugal'
},
{
    'name': 'Ariana Grande',
    'follower_count': 183,
    'description': 'Musician and actress',
    'country': 'United States'
}
]
```

Comment: *whatever I tried it didn't work.* Please share what you tried, then we can help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate random integers between 0 and 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996904/generate-random-integers-between-0-and-9) or better yet [How can I randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-can-i-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Comment: Look into `random.choice`. It doesn't matter than the objects in the list are dictionaries. Choosing a random object from a list is a standard problem with a standard solution.

Comment: When I use random.choice it prints out the whole list, and I just want to print out a single dictionary.

Comment: @FraneCal `random.choice(data)` does give me a single dictionary...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Okey, it does to me to now, but it didn't before. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
print(random.choice(data))

#Output1
{'name': 'Cristiano Ronaldo', 'follower_count': 215, 'description': 'Footballer', 'country': 'Portugal'}

print(random.choice(data))
#Output2
{'name': 'Ariana Grande', 'follower_count': 183, 'description': 'Musician and actress', 'country': 'United States'}

# UPDATE 2 (To select more than one key from same random dictionary)

random_index = random.randrange(len(data)-1)
print(data[random_index]["name"])
print(data[random_index]["follower_count"])
```

Comment: I want to print only one random dictionary from a list.

Comment: Check the above result. we will get only one random dictionary.

Comment: Okay, and how can I only print out, let's say the name without the rest in the dictionary, e.g. Christiano Ronaldo?

Comment: print( random.choice(data)["name"] )

Comment: One more thing and I'm done, can I print out more values from a single dictionary, e.g. (this doesn't work but just to show you):  print(random.choice(data)["name"]["follower_count"]), so to print out: Christiano Ronaldo, 215

Comment: In Python dictionary, "keys" like "name","follower_count" are unique so . Either you do `print(random.choice(data)["name"])`  and  `print(random.choice(data)["follower_count"])` in separate line  Or, run a for loop.

Comment: If I print it out in a separate line I get values from a different dictionary and I want to get values from the same dictionary. How can I do that?

Comment: You are correct.  I have made an #UPDATE  on above solution . It will work

Comment: @FraneCal you are in need of a good Python tutorial. `random.choice(data)` gives you a random dictionary from your list, can you not simply assign this to a variable and use it? `random_dict = random.choice(data)` and then `print(random_dict["name"])` etc.?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am learning Python at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice):

```py
import random

random.choice(data)
```

Comment: I know about that and it prints out the whole list, and I want to print out a single dictionary.